# Semantic -release not generate commit message with version number

Tags: github, npm, version, changelog, semantic-release

I am trying to use https://github.com/semantic-release/release-notes-generator

For example if my present version is

v1.0.0
when I added a fix and commit message as below.

fix: I made a fix.

I can see v1.0.1

In changeLog.md file I can see the updated version with the commit message I given.

v1.0.1
**I made a fix.**

But I edited the release.config.js

"@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
{
preset: "conventionalcommits",
"releaseRules": [
{ "type": "build", "release": "patch" }
]

```
    },
```

So in build, i expected same as fix. I mean a patch.
I expect if I do build: It is a build commit,

v1.0.2 **It is a build commit**

But I see only v1.0.2. I can't see the commit message.